# how to use createAndFillWorkbook() in exceljs?

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I followed the documentation

```
var workbook = createAndFillWorkbook();
```

and I get this
    error Object # has no method 'createAndFillWorkbook'

even if I required exceljs already

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");
```

What I wanted to do was to create a report but I am somehow confused on the documentation because it does not say here how to use the createAndFillWorkbook() method it just says here to use it right away.

I referred here in the documentation: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#writing-xlsx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**createAndFillWorkbook();** does not mean a function.(maybe pseudo function)

You must create some workbook then fill content.

See below.

```
// create workbook by api.
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

// must create one more sheet.
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");

// you can create xlsx file now.
workbook.xlsx.writeFile("C:\\somepath\\some.xlsx").then(function() {
    console.log("xls file is written.");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var excel = require("exceljs");
var workbook1 = new excel.Workbook();
workbook1.creator = 'Me';
workbook1.lastModifiedBy = 'Me';
workbook1.created = new Date();
workbook1.modified = new Date();
var sheet1 = workbook1.addWorksheet('Sheet1');
var reColumns=[
    {header:'FirstName',key:'firstname'},
    {header:'LastName',key:'lastname'},
    {header:'Other Name',key:'othername'}
];
sheet1.columns = reColumns;
workbook1.xlsx.writeFile("./uploads/error.xlsx").then(function() {
    console.log("xlsx file is written.");
});
```

This is my sample code which works for me.

Comment: what if I want to fill the rows inside each column?

Comment: @Liverpool - did you figured out how to do it ? I also want to do the samething

Comment: To add rows: `sheet1.addRows([{firstname: "Name", lastname: "Last", othername: "Other"}])`

Comment: does this work on Angular 5 or Angular 2? Because I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

Comment: This is for [tag:node.js]